# slow loading content via AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, optimization

I have modal box in which I add content to this box via AJAX ( data from database ), but here is a problem. This content is loaded very slowly. It happened that i open modal and after 4 or 5 sec appears a content.

I set  content like this :

```
$("#someIdInModal").html(""+dataFromDatabase);
```

So how you think where is problem ? I need to buy better server? xD or there is some faster method than this?

Comment: the code you provided is executed client-side after dataFromDatabase is initialized. can you actually post the ajax call?

Comment: $.get("file.php",{ id:id}).done(function(data){
     // in data i get eg. Juri
     $("#modalSurname").html(data);
});

Comment: Sorry, we cannot say what causes the delay. Only you can, since only you have access to your system. In general that approach must be slower than sending the data with the page load, since it is fetched only after the whole page has loaded. How long that additional round trip takes depends on many factors: page size and complexity, client performance, server performance, network latency and throughput, server performance and load, execution complexity, ...

Comment: How long does the database query take if you execute it on the commandline?

Comment: Process html on server is not the best solution. Try to delegate this function to the javascript/jQuery.

Comment: when i execute this command in sql i get 14 rows in 0.0019 seconds

Comment: if you open "file.php" directly in your browser (no ajax) how long does it take to load?

Comment: when i open file.php in my browser it take 161 ms to load

Comment: I've had similar slow issues on Windows Server 2012 r2 when querying a local database in PHP when using localhost as the host instead of 127.0.0.1 (to rephrase, the IP address works much quicker for me). Dunno if that'll factor in, but it irritated me for a while until I attempted the change.

Comment: "mark.hch" - i will try :)